# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type .Object literal may only specify known properties

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am inserting the data in Firebase db, once I submit the form data inserted successfully but am getting the error in TypeScript file, can any tell me what I am doing wrong? In the code.

Here is my code of registerpage.ts

```ts
regPhotographer = {} as RegPhotographer;

  regPhotographerRef$: AngularFireList<RegPhotographer[]>;

  constructor( private db: AngularFireDatabase, public router: Router ) { 
    this.regPhotographerRef$ = this.db.list('register');
  }

 addPhotographer(regPhotographer: RegPhotographer): void{
        this.regPhotographerRef$.push({
          fname: this.regPhotographer.fname,<!--The Error Line-->
          lname: this.regPhotographer.lname,
          location: this.regPhotographer.location,
          area: this.regPhotographer.area,
          amount: this.regPhotographer.amount,
          pin: this.regPhotographer.pin 
        });
```

Here is my registeruser.ts page code.

```ts
export interface RegPhotographer {
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
    location: string;
    area: string;
    amount: string;
    pin: string;
}
```

Comment: Please add the error as a code block in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `AngularFireList` is of type `RegPhotographer` not `RegPhotographer[]`. It is already a list not a list of arrays.

```
regPhotographerRef$: AngularFireList<RegPhotographer>;
```